# I am doing a Lottery smart contract in solidity but sometimes when I execute the setWinner function I get an error. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am doing a Lottery smart contract in solidity but sometimes when I execute the setWinner function I get an error. Can someone tell me why? I starting to program so I know my code isn't the best, I accept some recommendations. For exemple, for pick a random number, I took the hash of the timestamp and then I divided in 8 parts, each one for one number of the lottery game. Is there a better way to do it, instead of dividing it by two each time to get a random number?

```
function setWinner() public {

    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(block.timestamp));


    bytes4[2] memory x0 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x0, hash)
        mstore(add(x0, 4), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x1 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x1, hash)
        mstore(add(x1, 8), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x2 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x2, hash)
        mstore(add(x2, 12), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x3 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x3, hash)
        mstore(add(x3, 16), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x4 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x4, hash)
        mstore(add(x4, 20), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x5 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x5, hash)
        mstore(add(x5, 24), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x6 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x6, hash)
        mstore(add(x6, 28), hash)
    }
    bytes4[2] memory x7 = [bytes4(0), 0];
    assembly {
        mstore(x7, hash)
        mstore(add(x7, 32), hash)
    }

    uint n0 = uint32 (x0[1]); 
    n0 = n0%numberMax;
    uint n1 = uint32 (x1[1]); 
    n1 = n1%numberMax;
    uint n2 = uint32 (x2[1]); 
    n2 = n2%numberMax;
    uint n3 = uint32 (x3[1]); 
    n3 = n3%numberMax;
    uint n4 = uint32 (x4[1]); 
    n4 = n4%numberMax;
    uint n5 = uint32 (x5[1]); 
    n5 = n5%numberMax;
    uint n6 = uint32 (x6[1]); 
    n6 = n6%numberMax;
    uint n7 = uint32 (x7[1]); 
    n7 = n7%numberMax;

    //emit numbersCheck(n0,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7);

    uint[qntNumbers] memory tabNumbers = [n0,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7];

    quickSort(tabNumbers,0,tabNumbers.length -1);
    //emit tabCheck(tabNumbers);

    /*for (uint i=0;i<tabNumbers.length;i++){

        if (tabNumbers[i]==0){
                tabNumbers[i]= 60;                
            }
        if ( (i <= tabNumbers.length)&& (tabNumbers[i]==tabNumbers[i+1])){

            tabNumbers[i+1]= tabNumbers[i+1] + 1;

        }
    }
    quickSort(tabNumbers,0,tabNumbers.length -1);*/
    //emit tabCheck(tabNumbers);
    removeDoubles(tabNumbers);

    winnerGame = tabNumbers;

}
```

Comment: What exact are you getting?

Comment: It says that the transaction was mined but failed. In etherscan it tells me it run out of gas, take a look: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9b8bcc9568248b7785b66f51440505b11abb813fa596cbac5be6c40cb5b5a2e0

Comment: It says that the transaction was mined but failed. In etherscan it tells me [invalid opcode Oxfe] https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x03e23da1ed05f8f709dfbb413674af9d8e2d9e1199fda24efeed29db850b6aa8

Comment: There are these two erros, but sometimes it works. So I'm a little lost

Comment: All these transactions failed https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x214e7b3ba7bd8c7afd2ec06f93a1f7b3c2f489531137239a1923f8c4f595966d

Answer (score 1):

`block.timestamp` is a bad source of entropy. You should avoid it to keep your contract safe from malicious participants.

When submitting blocks, miners determine the value of block.timestamp and so could trivially affect the outcome of your lottery.

You might refer to these similar SO questions:

- [How-to generate a random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848948/how-to-generate-a-random-number)
- [How can we generate multiple random number in ethereum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467248/how-can-we-generate-multiple-random-number-in-ethereum)