# How to generate random words in solidity based on a string of letters

Tags: random, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I would like to make a word generation function based on the letters of the alphabet, but I don't know how to proceed. I would like to generate 12 words

```
string letters public = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

But I don't understand how I could proceed in solidity to generate

For numbers, I do this

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract RandomNumbers{
    function random(uint number) public view returns(uint){
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,block.difficulty,  
        msg.sender))) % number;
    }
}
```

But for words, I don't know how I could proceed

Answer (score 1):

```
contract MiniTest {

    string public letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    // I needed to add this to the random function to generate a different random number
    uint counter =1;

    // size is length of word
    function randomString(uint size) public  payable returns(string memory){
        bytes memory randomWord=new bytes(size);
        // since we have 26 letters
        bytes memory chars = new bytes(26);
        chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (uint i=0;i<size;i++){
            uint randomNumber=random(26);
            // Index access for string is not possible
            randomWord[i]=chars[randomNumber];
        }
        return string(randomWord);
    }

    function random(uint number) public payable returns(uint){
        counter++;
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,block.difficulty,  
        msg.sender,counter))) % number;
    }
}
```

- I slightly changed the random function because it was generating the same random number so the result for 5 characters was like "jjjjj".
- string in solidity has no index property. so we have to work with bytes and then convert it to string

Here is the proof of work:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't return the string to me like it returns it to you. I'm wodering why?

Comment: I got thisSend data to method 'randomString' with ["20"] from 0xc7A4Aa31DB05E89d443DeBc2CafCE713AA6DfCd3 at contract address 0xa8477e9c5C14eC2Ae4954234e047d26C1c522ECb

Comment: does it return the string

Answer (score 1):

I just improved the answer of @Yilmaz to make the functions **view** only from **payable**.

There is an additional function called **roll()** which outputs true or false based on chance. The 101 within roll() can be altered to 10001 to make the odds  down to 0.01% or you can make it dynamic by passing a parameter in place of 101.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Random {

    //Roll Chance

    function roll(uint256 number) public view returns (bool) {
        uint256 d = uint256(
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp))
        ) % 101;
        if (d <= number) return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Random Number Generator
    
    function random(uint256 number, uint256 counter)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return
            uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        block.timestamp,
                        block.difficulty,
                        msg.sender,
                        counter
                    )
                )
            ) % number;
    }

    //Random String Generator (Max length 14)

    function randomString(uint256 length) public view returns (string memory) {
        require(length <= 14, "Length cannot be greater than 14");
        require(length >= 1, "Length cannot be Zero");
        bytes memory randomWord = new bytes(length);
        // since we have 62 Characters
        bytes memory chars = new bytes(62);
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            uint256 randomNumber = random(62, i);
            // Index access for string is not possible
            randomWord[i] = chars[randomNumber];
        }
        return string(randomWord);
    }
}
```

I hope this Helps.