# Getting a random number with Chainlink VRF

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm trying to generate a random number with Chainlink VRF for a raffle system. This number should have a maximum value of `ticketOwners.length` and a minimum of 0, as I'll be getting the index of the array to pick as winner.

I currently have this code, which returns `uint256: 0` whenever calling getRandomNumber(). Aside from the vulnerabilities of this code I'm solely looking for help on generating this number.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract Random is VRFConsumerBase {
    bytes32 internal immutable keyHash;
    uint256 internal immutable fee;
    uint256 public immutable ticketPrice;

    uint256 public result;
    address payable[] public ticketOwners;

    constructor (
        address _ChainlinkVRFCoordinator,
        address _ChainlinkLINKToken,
        bytes32 _ChainlinkKeyHash,
        uint256 _ticketPrice
    ) VRFConsumerBase (
        _ChainlinkVRFCoordinator,
        _ChainlinkLINKToken
    ) {
        keyHash = _ChainlinkKeyHash;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;
        ticketPrice = _ticketPrice;
    }

    function enterRaffle() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= ticketPrice, "Invalid ticket price");
        ticketOwners.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        result = randomness;
    }
}
```

Comment: does `getRandomNumber`  run correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably using incorrect addresses for the parameters. Chainlink has two main variations. Since you are using `VRFConsumerBase` this is VRf V1, you can get addresses from [here](https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v1/supported-networks). I used those for goerli:

```
link address           = 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
key hash               = 0x0476f9a745b61ea5c0ab224d3a6e4c99f0b02fce4da01143a4f70aa80ae76e8a

ChainlinkVRFCoordinator= 0x2bce784e69d2Ff36c71edcB9F88358dB0DfB55b4
```

After you deploy the contract, you have to send link token to the contract, because you need to pay for the `fee` parameter that you set. [link token faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/)

You press on `getRandomNumber` button and you need to wait a little bit upto a minute. then your `result` value be set

here is the proof work:

[image]